# AppHarbor and Xml Documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, appharbor

I'm getting started to use AppHarbor with a existing application. 
But I'm stuck in a problem.

I'm using auto generate documentation for my asp.net MVC(5.2.2) and Web Api(5.2.0) application.

The version of the help page is 5.2.2 and the description about how to use is on the link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages 
The Help Pages uses a XML file that is generated on the build on the location "~\App_Data\XmlDocument.xml". 
But the appHarbor don't generate or deploy this file so anyone could give me a tip?

Thanks a lot, 
Bruno 
(sorry about my english)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, turned out I had enabled xmldoc just for Debug configuration, while AppHarbor was using Release.